# net::ERR CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED page is shown in my mobile web app for android 9.0 using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, xml, cordova, phonegap

I am creating my web app using phonegap and it works fine but I come to know that it is not working in android 9 pie, it shows web page not found with the below message

> net::ERR CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

I tried to rectify it by adding the below code in my network-security-config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
        <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="system" />
            </trust-anchors>
        </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

And also added the below lines in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest... >
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But I do not get it right. Can anyone help me with the solution ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod I worked on the solutions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted , but I didn't get it right

Answer (score 0):

This simple code works for me:

*network_security_config.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

And in AndroidManifest file:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Comment: Not sure why it does not work for you. You should check if your urls use HTTPS instead of HTTP